# iphone : Settings.bundle returns null value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I was using xCode 3.2 and then moved to xCode 4.2 and getting some values from Settings.bundle ... it was working fine.

Mean while I need to edit some values in Settings.bundle but The Root.plist file was not showing so I follow the below procedure but did not make any change in file.

```
1) Click on the Settings.Bundle file, go over to the utilities window,
and look in the File Inspector.
2) Using the drop-down, change the file type to 'Application Bundle'
```

After that I could see Root.plist but now could not get its values in application. Actually getting **Null** instead of value.

Below is code and image of Settings.bundle

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
host = [defaults stringForKey:@"meter_preference"];
if(host == nil)
{
    host = @"10.20.20.1";
    DDLogError(@"Meter host is nil from NSUserDefaults, defaulting to %@", host);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution, just call the below code in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions to initialize User defaults. and it works

Replace `somePropertyYouExpect` in first line with property you stored in User Defaults.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"somePropertyYouExpect"])  {

    NSString  *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString  *settingsPropertyListPath = [mainBundlePath
                                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.bundle/Root.plist"];

    NSDictionary *settingsPropertyList = [NSDictionary 
                                          dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:settingsPropertyListPath];

    NSMutableArray      *preferenceArray = [settingsPropertyList objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];
    NSMutableDictionary *registerableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (int i = 0; i < [preferenceArray count]; i++)  { 
        NSString  *key = [[preferenceArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Key"];

        if (key)  {
            id  value = [[preferenceArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"];
            [registerableDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
        }
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:registerableDictionary]; 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
}
```

Comment: Same issue with XCode 6.3 but your solution is still working.

Answer (score 1):

From your code , try this thinks..

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    host = [defaults stringForKey:@"meter_preference"];
    if(!host == nil)
    {
        host = @"10.20.20.1";
        DDLogError(@"Meter host is nil from NSUserDefaults, defaulting to %@", host);
    }
```

OR

Review this link may be helped you...

[iPhone - reading Setting.bundle returns wrong values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491394/iphone-reading-setting-bundle-returns-wrong-values)

[NSUserDefaults Settings Bundle Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766979/nsuserdefaults-settings-bundle-plist)